# How can I show SQL data in a SharePoint Server 2013 list?

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, sql-server

I have one table in SQL database.

```
ID  Name  Address
 1  pavi  chennai
 2  priya Bangalore
```

In SharePoint, I want to show above SQL table in a task list programmatically via C#.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add SQL Server data to SharePoint list using one of the following way.

1. Use BCS to insert data in SharePoint list from SQL Server table.
   Have a look at this link for better understanding. [SharePoint List From SQL Server Table (External Content Type with SharePoint Designer)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mind_talks/2012/04/03/sharepoint-list-from-sql-server-table-external-content-type-with-sharepoint-designer/)
2. You can refer this article [What is the best way to import SQL table data in sharepoint 2010 list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744307/what-is-the-best-way-to-import-sql-table-data-in-sharepoint-2010-list) which include the approach of using excel.

Please let me know if this is helpful for you?

Thanks

Comment: Programmatically it is not possible ?

Comment: One more doubt in my system i dont have SQL server how can i connect remotely i know the username and password.I used this link but is not connecting
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3250/connect-to-sql-servers-in-another-domain-using-windows-authentication/

Comment: yes it is possible by CSOM and Server Side Object Model and you can do it using Powershell as well.

Comment: For connecting to database you can use Management Studio

Comment: How can i open Management Studio i did not find in my system

Comment: you need to download it . And for Code why you need Server Side  ?

Comment: We are working on SharePoint server only. In client they are using our product they want to display the SQL data to SharePoint(server) List.

Comment: so you can use BCS .It is the best way for connection

Comment: i have already shared it with you please check answer

Comment: Hi i try to install sql  Management Studio but error was coming.This program has compatibility issues. I want to connect my colleague system Sql server how to connect?

Comment: you can directly connect to visual studio database to add connection in server explorer or you can try this link http://erolbalci.com/how-to-check-sql-database-connection-without-server-management-studio-on-windows/

Comment: Hi in my system i was uninstall sql server after that sharepoint site also not working pls help me how do i reinstall uninstall sql server in windows server 2012

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39494/discussion-between-codec-and-kavitha).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the data from external SQL database into SharePoint would be through Business Connectivity Services. SharePoint 2013 has a new type of List called the External List which is used for displaying data that comes from Business Connectivity Services (BCS). You can connect with any external source (in your case it is a SQL database table) and can create a list from that source.

This good reference article can help you to get your SQL data into SharePoint:
[Get Data from a SQL table through SharePoint Designer 2013.](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-create-external-list-including-database-from-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx)

But if you really want to stick to C# programming and want to directly show the SQL data into a task list then there are several project templates you can work, but if I was you I would have preferred developing a SharePoint Add-in in Visual Studio:

[Develop SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163794.aspx)

[What are SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930.aspx)

Write a code in your SharePoint Add-in that connects to SQL database as explained here: [Retrieve data from a SQL Server database in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171794/retrieve-data-from-a-sql-server-database-in-c-sharp)

Once you get the data from SQL, update this data to SharePoint 2013 task list via any method you know - example SharePoint REST API. For your reference: [Updating List Items in SharePoint 2013 Using REST API](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/472cc1/updating-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api/)